# How to take a photo from relative path for Background in a Windows Form, Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to put a photo on relative path for background form. At this time is with absolute path and I want to change to relative path.

```
this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + @"\RoundGame_Backgrounds\StartPage1.jpg");
```

I tried that. This is from the class, because the class is inherited from the `Form` class.

This is the main folder 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g36ZV.jpg

I use net framework 4.5.2.

Comment: It is a folder in your project.  Are you planning to ship the project as well as the final executable to your customer?  Consider adding a post-build event that creates the folder in the output directory as well, use xcopy /d /s

Comment: Add "StartPage1.jpg" file to your project and select it propertiy "Copy to output directory" as "Copy if newer". After that folder will be automatically copied on each build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at: [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"..\..\..\imgs\test.jpg"));
```

In my case, I've placed test.jpg in folder imgs which is at project's root level.